# Elements that satisfy an equation in an affine Artin group of type $\widetilde{A}_2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

In order to properly express my question, lets set the notation. Consider the group
$$A[\widetilde{A}_2]:=\langle a,b,c\ |\ aba=bab,aca=cac,bcb=cbc\rangle,$$
that is, an Artin group of type $\widetilde{A}_2$, and let $\varphi:A[\widetilde{A}_2]\longrightarrow A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ be the automorphism defined as
$$\varphi(a)=b,\quad \varphi(b)=c\quad \textrm{and}\quad \varphi(c)=a.$$
I am looking forward to find every non trivial elements $\alpha\in A[\widetilde{A}_2]$, if there are any, that satisfy the realtion
$$\alpha\varphi^2(\alpha^2)=\varphi(\alpha^2)\alpha,$$
where $\varphi^2:=\varphi\circ\varphi$.

I have not done much improvement in this problem, but there are some results that might be helpful:

1. The center of $A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ is trivial.
2. The outer automotphism group of $A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ is isomoprhic to $\mathfrak{S}_3\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathfrak{S}_3$ is the symmetric group of order $6$ conform by automorphisms that are the permutations of the generators (for instance, both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^2$) and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is conform by the automorphism that send the generators to their inverses.
3. The element $\varphi^2(\alpha)\alpha\varphi(\alpha)$ is in the centralizer of $\alpha^2$ in $A[\widetilde{A}_2]$. We can see this by applying $\varphi$ to the equation. Indeed
   $$\alpha\varphi^2(\alpha^2)=\varphi(\alpha^2)\alpha\xrightarrow[]{\varphi}\varphi(\alpha)\alpha^2=\varphi^2(\alpha^2)\varphi(\alpha)\xrightarrow[]{\varphi}\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)=\alpha^2\varphi^2(\alpha),$$
   therefore
   $$\varphi^2(\alpha)\alpha\underbrace{\varphi(\alpha)\alpha^2}=\varphi^2(\alpha)\underbrace{\alpha\varphi^2(\alpha^2)}\varphi(\alpha)=\underbrace{\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)}\alpha\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha^2\varphi^2(\alpha)\alpha\varphi(\alpha).$$
4. The group $A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ is torsion-free and co-Hopfian.
5. We have that
   $$\varphi(\alpha)\alpha^2\varphi(\alpha)=\varphi^2(\alpha)\alpha^2\varphi^2(\alpha).$$
   Again, it is derived similarly as in the point 3.
6. There is a normal form, called *Shortlex Minimal Form*, which is explained in the article *Artin group of large type are shortlex automatic with regular geodesics*, written by D. Holt and S. Rees and published in 2012.
7. $\varphi$ has not trivial fixed points.

I will greatly appreciate any help with the problem, and thanks in advance.

**A bit of improvement:** I have proven that an element $\alpha\in A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ satisfy that
$$\alpha\varphi(\alpha)\alpha=\varphi(\alpha)\alpha\varphi(\alpha)$$
if and only if $\alpha\in\{1,a,b,c,a^{-1},b^{-1},c^{-1}\}$. This is proven from the fact that $\varphi$ has non trivial fixed points and that the group is co-Hopfian. Now, using the result sugested by @kabenyuk, notice that since $\varphi(\alpha)\alpha^2\varphi(\alpha)=\varphi^2(\alpha)\alpha^2\varphi^2(\alpha)$ and $\alpha^2=\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)\varphi^2(\alpha^{-1})$, we have that
$$\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)=\varphi^2(\alpha^2)\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha).$$
If we take a look in this equation, my intuition says that the only element that satisfy this is the identity. Nevertheless, notice that we can write this as
$$\varphi^2(\alpha^2)=\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)\varphi^2(\alpha^{-1})\varphi(\alpha^{-1})=\left(\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha^{-1})\varphi(\alpha^{-1})\right)^2.$$
Therefore, there exists an element $\beta\in A[\widetilde{A}_2]$ such that
$$\varphi^2(\alpha)=\beta\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha^{-1})\varphi(\alpha^{-1})\beta^{-1},$$
that is
$$\varphi^2(\alpha)\beta\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)=\beta\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha).$$
Also, we know that $\beta$ is in the centralizer of $\varphi^2(\alpha^2)$, since
$$\varphi^2(\alpha^2)=\beta\varphi(\alpha)\varphi^2(\alpha)\varphi(\alpha^2)\varphi^2(\alpha^{-1})\varphi(\alpha^{-1})\beta^{-1}=\beta\varphi^2(\alpha^2)\beta^{-1}.$$

Comment: Is it true in this group that from the equality $x^2=y^2$ follows $x=y$? If the answer is yes, it seems to me that this would simplify the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi @kabenyuk. I am not sure that this is true. Does this property has a name? I ask in order to seach for information.

Comment: Group with single-valued root extraction. Such are torsion-free nilpotent group. In the Artin braid group $B_n$ is [unique up to conjugacy](https://msp.org/agt/2003/3-2/agt-v3-n2-p18-p.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @kabenyuk! I will try to ask more information about this fact, and I will also ask the author of the article that you cited (it happends to be one of the PhD tutor of my PhD tutor).

Comment: Hi again @kabenyuk. I have found [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-009-0530-y) where it is proven the that the result you mentioned for braids holds for this group too.